# How do I create a login for my game using sqlite3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pygame

I am currently trying to figure out how to add a login screen to my game that takes the entered player name and keeps track of the players high score, any help with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite: How to make a table, insert some values and read it with python:

```py
import sqlite3

# open connection
connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# create table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists scores (player text, score int)")
connection.commit()

# insert value
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player1", 180))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player2", 50))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player3", 300))
connection.commit()

# get value
cursor.execute("SELECT score FROM scores WHERE player = 'player2'")
output = cursor.fetchall()
print(output)

# close connection
connection.close()
```

First, I open the file `db.db`. Then I create a table and save it with `commit()`. Then I inserted some values. Then I got the values and print them to the console.

How to do the pygame window thing:

```py
import pygame

# set window size
X = 400
Y = 400

# init pygame window
pygame.init()
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Window title')

# set pygame colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# init text 
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
text = font.render('Text', True, black, white)

# center text
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (X // 2, Y // 2)

# loop
while True:
    display_surface.fill(white)
    display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
 
    # if close button quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        # update window
        pygame.display.update()
```

and if you combine it, the code will look like this:

```py
import pygame
import sqlite3

# sqlite
# open connection
connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# create table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists scores (player text, score int)")
connection.commit()

# insert value
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player1", 180))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player2", 50))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?)", ("player3", 300))
connection.commit()

# get value
cursor.execute("SELECT score FROM scores WHERE player = 'player2'")
output = str(cursor.fetchall()[0][0])


# pygame
# set window size
X = 400
Y = 400

# init pygame window
pygame.init()
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Window title')

# set pygame colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# init text 
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
text = font.render(output, True, black, white)

# center text
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (X // 2, Y // 2)

# loop
while True:
    display_surface.fill(white)
    display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
 
    # if close button quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            connection.close()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        # update window
        pygame.display.update()
```

and the window like this:

[image: pygame window]

**Please comment, if this has worked for you, and accept the answer to help others with the same problem. If you are still struggling, comment what is not working.

Have a good day!:)**